# Working around the lack of enum inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, enums, interface

Classes Phone and Computer both implement the IDevice interface.

Phone has a PhoneStatus enum property, while Computer has a ComputerStatus enum property.
Moreover, they both have a method that returns some stuff based on their status property.

```
class Phone : IDevice
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public PhoneStatus Status { get; set; }
    
    IEnumerable<object> GetStuffByStatus(PhoneStatus status)
    {
        ...
    }
}

enum PhoneStatus
{
    On,
    Off
}

class Computer : IDevice
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public ComputerStatus Status { get; set; }
    
    IEnumerable<object> GetStuffByStatus(ComputerStatus status)
    {
        ...
    }
}

enum ComputerStatus
{
    Started,
    ShutDown,
    Booting,
    ShuttingDown
}
```

I know inheritance is not an option for enums, so the question is: is there any way to force the classes implementing IDevice to write their own DeviceStatus property (which could be implemented as a PhoneStatus or a ComputerStatus) and GetStuffByStatus method? Something like this

```
interface IDevice
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Manufacturer { get; set;}
    DeviceStatus Status { get; set;}
    
    IEnumerable<object> GetStuffByStatus(DeviceStatus status);
}
```

Comment: Just a side note (assuming that you want to `GetStuffByStatus()` to get 'stuff' based on the `Status` of the device instance that you are calling the method on): `GetStuffByStatus()` should not need any input parameters. It should simply use the device instance's `Status` in the method body.

Comment: you may use int as status ... and then implement interface explicity and add same method which use typed enum

Comment: like [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mV1qWX)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public interface IDevice<T> where T: Enum
{
    string Name         { get; set; }
    string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    T Status { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<object> GetStuffByStatus(T status);
}
```

Then implementing classes must declare an enum of some kind for the status:

```
public class Computer: IDevice<ComputerStatus>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public ComputerStatus Status { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetStuffByStatus(ComputerStatus status)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

If you need to, you could extract the common parts that are not dependent on the Status enum into a base interface:

```
public interface IDevice
{
    string Name         { get; set; }
    string Manufacturer { get; set; }
}

public interface IDeviceWithStatus<T>: IDevice where T: Enum
{
    T Status { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<object> GetStuffByStatus(T status);
}
```

Then you'll still be able to access the common parts via `IDevice` and the status-dependent parts via `IDeviceWithStatus<T>`.

Comment: but of course then there would be no common interface between Computer and Phone...

Comment: @Selvin Yes, true

Comment: yes, an interesting solution, thanks, even if @Selvin is right